# How can I test a catch block using jest nodejs?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

How can i test the catch block on a es6 Class

```
const fs = require('fs');
class Service {
  constructor(accessToken) {
    this.accessToken = accessToken;
  }

  async getData() { // eslint-disable-line class-methods-use-this
    try {


      const data = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/models/mockData.json`, { encoding: 'utf8' });
      const returnData = JSON.parse(data);
      return returnData;
    } catch (err) {
      return err;
    }
  }
}

module.exports = Service;
```

using jest how can i write the test case to cover the catch block also.

Answer (score 5):

You can mock the method `readFileSync` from `fs` to force it to return `undefined`. `JSON.parse(undefined)` will throw an error, thus you can check the catch side of the code.

```
  fs.readFileSync = jest.fn()
  fs.readFileSync.mockReturnValue(undefined);
```

First of all, in the `catch` side you should throw the error. Just returning it is not a good practise when managing errors, from my point of view. But there is people doing it.

```
const fs = require('fs');

class Service {
  constructor(accessToken) {
    this.accessToken = accessToken;
  }

  async getData() { // eslint-disable-line class-methods-use-this
    try {
      const data = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/models/mockData.json`, { encoding: 'utf8' });
      const returnData = JSON.parse(data);
      return returnData;
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }
}
```

Having this code, you can actually test your `catch` block code in two different ways with Jest:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  fs.readFileSync = jest.fn();
});

afterEach(() => {
  fs.readFileSync.mockClear();
});

test('Async expect test', () => {
  fs.readFileSync.mockReturnValue(undefined);

  const result = service.getData();

  expect(result).rejects.toThrow();
});

test('Async / await test', async() => {
  fs.readFileSync.mockReturnValue(undefined);

  try {
    await service.getData();
  } catch (err) {
    expect(err.name).toEqual('TypeError');
    expect(err.message).toEqual(`Cannot read property 'charCodeAt' of undefined`);
 }
});
```

Both of them imply to mock the `readFileSync` method from `fs` module as I suggested before. You can even mock the whole `fs` module with Jest. Or you could just mock the `JSON.parse`. There are plenty of options to be able to test the `catch` block.

Comment: can you just update the answer i am not getting it, also should i mock fs module also little bit confused

Comment: I had a typo that might be confusing. Also added the examples you requested.

Answer (score 1):

Jest has its own method for testing exception, you can use [toThrow](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tothrowerror). It looks something like this

```
test('throws on octopus', () => {
  expect(() => {
    drinkFlavor('octopus');
  }).toThrow(); // Test the exception here
});
```

## Note

Since your function is *asynchronous*, try to explicitly define your error, then use `await` to resolve/reject it, After that you can check for the actual `rejection`

```
test('throws on octopus', () => {
  await expect(user.getUserName(3)).rejects.toEqual({
    error: 'User with 3 not found.',
  });
});
```

Comment: If want to test the `try/catch` and specifically the `catch` clause, your code needs to __throw__ an exception, instead of __return__. Try replacing `return err` with `throw err`

Comment: Expected the function to throw an error.
    But it didn't throw anything.
getting this error

Comment: I think that's because your function is _asynchronous_. Check the edit I just added